# Python script: how to fix CMake Error: Could not create named generator?

Tags: python, windows, cmake

- OS: Windows 10
- CMake: 3.18.2
- MSVC: 16.7.3

When I use command line I can generate build with following line

```
cmake -B "D:\Builds" -S "D:\src" -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A "x64"
```

When I use followed Pytnon script:

```
subprocess.call([
    '...\cmake.exe', 
    '-B "D:\Builds"',
    '-S "D:\src"',
    '-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"',
    '-A "x64"'
])
```

I receive an error:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator  "Visual Studio 16 2019"
```

Why it happens and how to fix it?

PS: this is not duplicate of any questions, this is new

**Update1**:
When I change generator line to the

```
'-G Visual Studio 16 2019'
```

I see the followed error:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator  Visual Studio 16 2019
```

So I think it is not doublequotes fall

Comment: Are you sure that given "CMake Error: Could not create named generator" is the **only** message you have got during running `cmake`? Normally, such messages are accompanied by other ones, which are also relevant to the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev its all that I see - only this line and followed set of generators that could be used. First of them is "Visual Studio 16 2019". I have idea that when I use Python script the environment variables dont pass to the cmake. But dont have any idea what to do.

Comment: OK. Now the problem is clear: double quotes in `"Visual Studio 16 2019"` become a **part** of the generator name.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, look at Update1 of my post, it not helps(

Comment: Yes, because a prepending **space** is also a part of the name. This cannot be found from your post, because you use "blockquote" formatting instead of "code". But source of your post clearly contains **two spaces** between `generator  Visual`. For the future: use only "code" formatting for error messages.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, yee, there are 2 spaces.... but I dont get what I should to do?

Comment: Specification `-G "Visual Studio 16 2019"` is **for command line**, where separate words denote separate arguments and double quotes are used for group separated words into the single parameter. In python code every parameter to `subprocess.call` is already a *single* one, and every inner space (or quotes) becomes a part of the parameter. Just use `'-G', 'Visual Studio 16 2019'` or `'-GVisual Studio 16 2019`. This is how **single**-letter options work in most cases: either space-separated option name and value `-<opt> <value>`, or combined: `-<opt><value>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have *two versions* of CMake installed. Be sure the one used in your Python script is greater than or equal to CMake version 3.14. The `Visual Studio 16 2019` generator is not available in earlier CMake versions.

You can test your CMake version used by the Python script by adding:

```
subprocess.call([
    '...\cmake.exe', 
    '--version'
])
```

Comment: Yes, I have 2 cmake versions installed. One is 3.17 and other 3.18.2. I use your script and see - "cmake version 3.18.2"

Answer (score 1):

For me, a similar problem was resolved by removing the quotes within the quotes in Python, as hinted at in @Tsyvarev's comment above. IOW:

```py
subprocess.call(['cmake', '-G', '"Visual Studio 16 2019"']) # Fails
subprocess.call(['cmake', '-G', 'Visual Studio 16 2019'])   # Succeeds
```

Or if you want one generator arg:

```py
subprocess.call(['cmake', '-G"Visual Studio 16 2019"']) # Fails
subprocess.call(['cmake', '-GVisual Studio 16 2019'])   # Succeeds
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following two commands:

```
echo_cmd = ["echo", '"Visual Studio 16 2019"']
subprocess.run(echo_cmd, check=True)
```

the result is `"Visual Studio 17 2022"`.

```
echo_cmd = ["echo", "Visual Studio 16 2019"]
subprocess.run(echo_cmd, check=True)
```

the result is `Visual Studio 17 2022`.

So that argument your CMake received is a string containing quotes, but it expects no quotes at all.